Trying to prove that if $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = b,$ where $b$ is constant, then $f(x)$ is exponential.
I know how to prove the converse, but I'm curious about how to prove it in the other direction. So far, what I have is this:
Assume that $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = b.$ Then,
\begin{align}
f(x+1)&=bf(x) \\
f(x+2)&=b^{2}f(x) \\
\vdots \\
f(x+k)&=b^{k}f(x).
\end{align}
Any tips are appreciated. Thank you.

What if $f(x)=b^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$?

How do you define exponential? Is $x$ real? $f(x)$ can be defined to be any values on $[0,1)$ and then extended to the real line.

$f(x+n)= b^k f(x)$ where $(x,f(x))$ graph consists of discrete line segments which is a set/collection of segment wise assumed linearities.

Don't wanna be that guy but ,
Take $f(x)=1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $$\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$
Maybe trivial but it came to mind.
But you can still argue $f(x)=1^x$. So I am wrong :D

As you have shown, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ you have $$
f(x+k)=b^kf(x)
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, this is not enough to prove that $f(x)$ is exponential. Instead:
Lemma: $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = b$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f(x) = \theta(x)b^x$ for some $1$-periodic function $\theta(x)$.
Proof: First, the "if" direction. Suppose $\theta(x)$ is one-periodic and define $f(x) = \theta(x)b^x$. One-periodic means $\theta(x+1) = \theta(x)$, so:$$
\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = \frac{\theta(x+1)b^{x+1}}{\theta(x)b^x} = b
$$
For the "only if" direction. Suppose $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=b$ for some constant $b$. Then $f(x+1) = bf(x)$. We define $\theta(x)=\frac{f(x)}{b^x}$ and show that $\theta(x)$ is one-periodic:$$
\theta(x+1) = \frac{f(x+1)}{b^{x+1}} = \frac{b f(x)}{b^x\cdot b} = \frac{f(x)}{b^x} = \theta(x)
$$
Q.E.D.
If you want to show that $f$ is exponential, you will need some additional constraints.  For example, if we also impose that $f$ is log-convex, it will necessarily be exponential: Suppose $f$ is a log-convex function with $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}=b$. Using the Lemma, we have that $f(x) = \theta(x) b^x$. Then $\log f(x) = \log \theta(x) + x\log b$ is convex. Since adding a linear function does not affect convexity, this implies $\log\theta(x)$ is convex. A periodic convex function must be constant, hence $\theta(x) = a$ for some $a$ and hence $f(x) = a b^x$ is exponential.

Sorry for the late reply, but thank you tons! Very clear.

actually, take $f(0) = 1$   and $f(1) = b,$   but fill in values of $f(x) $  for $0 < x < 1$   any way you like
for continuous piecewise linear  fill in a line segment, $f(x) = (b-1)x  + 1$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$
Not sure whether real analytic forces exponential, it might. The analogous material for the gamma function comes with the names Bohr Mollerup

Real analytic won't help. You can freely multiply the solution by $e^{\sin(2\pi n,x/b)}$ for any integer $n$ and it still will be a solution.

@JosBergervoet   what about log convex (and $C^\infty$)?  Seems promising
